# DDL queries using Grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a DBA tool on Oracle DB to manage multiple database servers using Grails. My application needs to create database users by taking user (DBA) inputs. Creating a new database user is a DDL statement. Can we write DDL statements in Grails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, dependency-inject the `dataSource` bean into a controller/service/etc. and get a connection from there. Then you can do any JDBC query you want. Your best bet is to use `groovy.sql.Sql` as it simplifies the workflow for doing JDBC.

You can also run queries from the Grails console (run `grails console` to launch it). Beans are available using property access notation from the implicit `ctx` variable which is the Spring ApplicationContext, so you can get the dataSource bean via `def dataSource = ctx.dataSource`

Here's an example in a Service:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyService {

   def dataSource

   def someMethod() {

      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

      String dml = '''\
         create table foo (
         ...
         )'''

      sql.execute(dml)
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the `dataSource` here automatically bind with the `dataSource defined in config?`

Comment: Yes, it's the bean that manages the connection pool that's configured in DataSource.groovy, and if you use multiple datasources, e.g. a second one named "dataSource_reporting", then there will be a bean with that name also and you can use it for queries in that datasource via `def dataSource_reporting`